# what is the difference between grpc stream error and TCP error

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-go

It is introduced in "google.golang.org/grpc/codes" that some errors can be generated by grpc and some cannot be generated, and the grpc stream should correspond to the stream in http2.0. Then I want to know whether it means that there is an error with the TCP connection when those grpc streams throw exceptions, so do I only need to reconnect the TCP connection, or do I have somes methods for only reconnect stream (such as reconnecting streams, etc.)

```
    for {
        request, err3 := stream.Recv()
        if err3 == io.EOF {
            return nil
        }
        if err3 != nil {
            return err3  // how can i handle this error (grpc generated)
        }
        do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC-go handles network level reconnections for you: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn

> A ClientConn encapsulates a range of functionality including name resolution, TCP connection establishment (with retries and backoff) and TLS handshakes. It also handles errors on established connections by re-resolving the name and reconnecting.

If the error returns an error and is not type `io.EOF`, it means that something went wrong (including network errors) and that you have to request a new stream: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/stream.go#L126 but you don't have to worry to create a new TCP connection.

> RecvMsg blocks until it receives a message into m or the stream is done. It returns io.EOF when the stream completes successfully. On any other error, the stream is aborted and the error contains the RPC status.

If it can't get a new stream, means that it can't connect to the server or that something is very wrong with it, but if it is a transient network error, you will eventually be able to get a new stream.